# Is there a faster way to add raster bricks containing NAs together in R?

Tags: r, terra

I have many large raster bricks that I want to add together. There are many NA values which means the default brick+brick misses many columns. Summing together using sum(.., na.rm = TRUE) is very slow.

Is there a better way using terra, something similar to base::Reduce perhaps?

See reprex below

```
library(terra)

## create 4 raster bricks with different values
set.seed(0)
b1 <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=5)
values(b1) <- rnorm(size(b1), 1, 0.2)
values(b1)[values(b1)<1] <- NA

b2 <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=5)
values(b2) <- rnorm(size(b2), 1, 0.2)
values(b2)[values(b2)<1] <- NA

b3 <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=5)
values(b3) <- rnorm(size(b3), 1, 0.2)
values(b3)[values(b3)<1] <- NA

b4 <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=5)
values(b4) <- rnorm(size(b4), 1, 0.2)
values(b4)[values(b4)<1] <- NA

## basic sum together
b5 <- b1+b2+b3+b4
## if any columns has an NA the entire column is NA
plot(b5)
```

[image: plot without na.rm = TRUE]

```
## ignoring NAs gives the result I want, however it is very slow
b6 <- sum(b1,b2,b3,b4, na.rm = TRUE)

plot(b6)
```

[image: plot with columns including NAs included]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution that might be faster if your raster bricks are big (e.g., >100MB each). With the small reproducible example, this option is much slower because of all the layer handling. But the idea is to take advantage of the functions that have been re-implemented in C++ in `terra` (see `?terra::app`).
This option also allows you to write individual layers of the final brick to disk.

```
fsum_bricks <- function(b1, b2, b3, b4) {
  bout <- rast(b1)
  for(i in seq_len(nlyr(bout))) {
    bout[[i]] <- app(c(b1[[i]], b2[[i]], b3[[i]], b4[[i]]), fun = 'sum', na.rm = T)
    # or consider saving each layer to disk
    # app(c(b1[[i]], b2[[i]], b3[[i]], b4[[i]]), fun = 'sum', na.rm = T, 
    #  filename = ...)
    
  }
  return(bout)
}

b7 <- fsum_bricks(b1, b2, b3, b4)
plot(b7)
```